# send csv or fill database?

Tags: mysql, csv, connection

I'm developing one app that store data locally and send CSV when internet is available.

The goal is to populate an on-line MySql db.

The question is: considering an environment with very low quality internet connection, is better to send data as CSV to check and then put in db or directly to db?

I suppose directly populate db is less expensive in terms of connection but is safe for db integrity and consistency if the data connection get lost?

Comment: How about a checksum check prior to import into a temp or work table? That would be above and beyond what your avg peer does.

Answer (score 0):

If you can insert the data with a single SQL statement, it will be treated as an atomic operation and either fail completely or succeed completely. If you need multiple insert statements, wrap the whole thing in a transaction so it gets treated as an atomic operation.